# Trying to understand 'this' inside Prorotype and Lambda functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-5

So today I was coding an AJAX object.

I created a *constructor*, ajaxObj:

```
    function ajaxObj( arg1, arg2, wrapper ) {
             this.form = arg1;
             this.btn  = arg2;
             this.msg  = "Update successful";

             this.url  = "process.php";
             this.wrap = wrapper; // this is the div the callback uses

             this.serial = null; // serialized form for POSTing

             this.callback = function () {
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  div.innerHTML = this.msg;
                  div.setAttribute( "id", "desiredID" );
                  this.wrap.appendChild(div);

             }

             this.btn.onclick = initXHR;
    }
```

There were to be several objects of type ajaxObj instantiated on the given page.  I wanted to include the functions that would not change and should be shared on the prototype:

```
ajaxObj.prototype = {
     constructor: ajaxObj,

     makeXHR: function () { 
               // cross browser XHR code returns XHR obj
     }

     makeSer: function () {
            this.serial = $(this.form).serialize();
     }

     initXHR: function () {
            // this is where shit gets weird!
            this.makeSer(); // makeSer function doesnt exit

            var http = this.makeXHR(); // makeXHR doesn't exist

            http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                     /* this function checked for 
                        http.status / http.readyState
                        and attempted to call this.callback() 
                        which of course didn't exist.

                        I also tried to change instance
                        properties here which did not work */
            }

            http.open( "POST", this.url, true ); /* this.url did not work
                                                     and had to be replaced
                                                     with "process.php"    */
            http.setRequestHeaders("Content-Type","application/x..."); // TL;DT
            http.send( this.serial ) // <--- this works just fine???
     }
```

I've looked at many of the similar questions and given great time and consideration to this over the past week.  I have my code working now, by **taking callback out of the constructor as well as by taking makeXHR() and makeSer() off of the prototype** and placing them all *in global scope*.

Despite the fact that I got my code working, to my chagrin, I still don't understand why **this.url** didn't work inside **xhr.open()** while this.serial *works* inside of **xhr.send()**

---

Bascally, why does 'this' work in some places of the prototype (such as replacing

```
ajaxObj.prototype = {
 .............
     initXHR: function () {
         makeSer();
      ....
      http.open( "POST", this.url, true );
      .... 
      http.send( this.serial );
      ....
}
```

with

```
ajaxObj.prototype = {
     .............
         initXHR: function () {
             this.serial = $(this.form).serialize();
             ....
             http.open( "POST", "process.php", true );
             .... 
             http.send(this.serial);
    }
```

....  Please, un-bewilder me.  I was under the impression that I had it figured out.  Setting that=this inside the constructor seems to not work when I use the var keyword, and obviously(things are not always so obvious with javascript) removing the var keyword sets *that* equal to values were instantiated with the most recent object instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just glancing over your code I can see that your initXHR function is only called when onclick of your target button fires.  If you inspect **this** within initXHR I'm sure you'll find it is your button.

I think that based on your current class design you will need to use the old

```
var self = this;
```

in your constructor, and make your initXHR a privileged function (within your constructor) in order to access it.  I've commented the code below to show you what I've added to your ctor.

```
function ajaxObj( arg1, arg2, wrapper ) {

     // Assign this -> self at the start of the func
     var self = this;

     this.form = arg1;
     this.btn  = arg2;
     this.msg  = "Update successful";

     this.url  = "process.php";
     this.wrap = wrapper;

     this.serial = null;

     this.callback = function () {
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.innerHTML = this.msg;
          div.setAttribute( "id", "desiredID" );
          this.wrap.appendChild(div);

     }

     // Make initXHR a privileged function, ie. one that has
     // access to private variables in ctor
     this.initXHR = function () {

         self.url // should be accessible here
     }

     this.btn.onclick = this.initXHR; // Assign it.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sure that I had tried that...  Only I had left the initXHR in the Prototype rather than putting it inside of the constructor.  This is exactly what i was trying to do.  

by the way, and completely off topic, I was just checking out Brendan Eich's website, and it looks as though some cool things lie in JavaScript's future :)

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  I'll have a nosey at his website, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Probably you called the function "wrong", i.e. not on the `ajaxObj` instance. Show us that invocation.

The reason why `this.serial` works and `this.url` does not is that you just explicitly assigned to `this.serial` right before - though it likely was not a property on the object you expected.

Comment: Your right - and this.serial seems to not work for all the forms on the page (there are 6 of them).  MDN is my homepage.  I've read a lot about the this keyword, and conducted my own experiments to try and understand it, but I'll give that article another read...